# Using a member of a type as a key in std::multiset

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, multiset

I am creating my own tree-like container in C++. Here is an outline of how I imagine it's structure:

```
//==========================================================
// Concept
//==========================================================
//
// RootNode -> Attributes
//          -> Nodes -> Attributes
//                   -> Nodes -> Attributes
//                            -> Nodes
//                             
// etc...
//==========================================================
```

I have named the type `DataTree` for now. The header looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

namespace LB{
    class DataTree;
    struct DataTreeComparitor{
        bool operator () (DataTree const & lhs, DataTree const & rhs) const;
        bool operator () (std::string const & lhs, DataTree const & rhs) const;
        bool operator () (DataTree const & lhs, std::string  const & rhs) const;
    };
    class DataTree{
    public:
        template <typename Type>
        Type getAttribute(std::string const & name) const{
            static_cast<Type>(*m_attributes.find(name));
        }

        DataTree getChild(std::string const & name) const;

        std::string getName(void) const;

    private:
        std::string m_name;

        std::multimap<std::string, std::string> m_attributes;
        std::multiset<DataTree, DataTreeComparitor> m_children;
    };
}
```

I would like to find elements in the container `m_children` using an `std::string`, which `DataTreeComparitor` would compare against the result of `getName()`.

However, when trying to call `find()` on `m_children`, I get the following error from `mingw32`:

```
    C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/BitBucket/LBC++/LBC++/DataTree.cpp:17:31: error: no matching function for call to 'std::multiset<LB::DataTree, LB::DataTreeComparitor>::find(const string&) const'
```

And this using `MSVC`:

```
    2   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::multiset<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [with _Kty=LB::DataTree, _Pr=LB::DataTreeComparitor, _Alloc=std::allocator<LB::DataTree>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const std::string)
            object type is: const std::multiset<LB::DataTree, LB::DataTreeComparitor, std::allocator<LB::DataTree>> c:\Users\Joshua\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp  46  21  Project1
```

Here is the implementation, with the problem line indicated through a comment:

```
#include "DataTree.h"

namespace LB{
    bool DataTreeComparitor::operator () (DataTree const & lhs, DataTree const & rhs) const{
        return lhs.getName() < rhs.getName();
    }

    bool DataTreeComparitor::operator () (std::string const & lhs, DataTree const & rhs) const{
        return lhs < rhs.getName();
    }

    bool DataTreeComparitor::operator () (DataTree const & lhs, std::string  const & rhs) const{
        return lhs.getName() < rhs;
    }

    DataTree DataTree::getChild(std::string const & name) const{
        return *m_children.find(name); // problem line
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me work out why the compiler isn't using `DataTreeComparitor` to compare `DataTree` against an `std::string`.

My question is, why isn't it doing so? As you can see, I've tried adding operator overloads to the comparitor where `std::string` is both the left hand operator and the right hand.

**Note:**

I know there are many essential features things missing from this `DataTree` type; it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `multiset<DataTree, DataTreeComparitor>::find` with an `std::string` parameter. That cannot work, because it requires a `DataTree`, and there is no conversion from `std::string` to `DataSet`.

You could fix this by adding an implicit converting constructor:

```
class DataTree{
public:
  DataTree(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {}
  ....
};
```

Comment: Is there no way I can do this through the comparitor?

Comment: @OMGtechy No, not in C++11. [C++14 has something that might work for this use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Heterogeneous_lookup_in_associative_containers).

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to C++14 then, and will use your solution in the meantime.  I can't imagine I'll be getting such features is `mingw32` for quite some time.